# HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect issue with Visual studion 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, asp.net-ajax

As I have migrated Web Application from 3.5 (VS 2008 ) to 4.0 Vs (2010)

Now i am having problem with **Response.Redirect**

As I in .aspx pages i have found the following solution and it is working fine.

old Code with is not Working in Vs2010

> Response.Redirect(Page.ResolveUrl(strURL));

And following is the code which is working for Redirecting the page.

> ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,
>   this.GetType(), "red",
>   "window.location.href='" + strURL +
>   "';", true);

But now I need to Redirect from the class library
So can any one guide me on the same.. i can i redirect .. AS I have try with

**HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(strURL);**
but it is  not working.

Comment: By NOT working, do you mean an `Exception` is thrown or simply, nothing happens?

Comment: Response.Redirect should still work. What exactly happens when "it doesn't work"? What does that "strUrl" contain and what did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Pass a reference to the response to the class library and use that to perform the redirect.